# Suspended orchestration service instance re-throwing the same unexpected exception after Resume

Tags: biztalk

I am getting below error, when i am trying to resume Suspended(resumable) orchestration instance.

Scenario: Request went thourgh DB2 Static solicit - Response port, and it got failed because of access permission denied. I can see two instances suspended in the admin console one is related to port and another one is related to orchestration. After fixing the credentials, suspended port instance got resumed but the orchestration one is keep on failing.

```
Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'Orchestration name'.
The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
InstanceId: ca927086-465d-40e8-93fe-c3a0e4c161f7
Shape name: 
ShapeId: 
Exception thrown from: segment -1, progress -1
Inner exception: An error occurred while processing the message, refer to the details section for more information 
Message ID: {96B72521-9833-48EF-BB2F-4A2E2265D697}
Instance ID: {F6FBC912-C9DC-489C-87F3-103FA1273FDC}
Error Description: The user does not have the authority to access the host resource. Check your authentication credentials or contact your system administrator. SQLSTATE: HY000, SQLCODE: -1000


Exception type: XlangSoapException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
Target Site: Void VerifyTransport(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Envelope, Int32, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Context)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured
at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.VerifyTransport(Envelope env, Int32 operationId, Context ctx)
at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Subscription.Receive(Segment s, Context ctx, Envelope& env, Boolean topOnly)
at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBase.GetMessageIdForSubscription(Subscription subscription, Segment currentSegment, Context cxt, Envelope& env, CachedObject location)
at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBase.GetMessageId(Subscription subscription, Segment currentSegment, Context cxt, Envelope& env, CachedObject location)
at (StopConditions stopOn)
at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Creating the above scenario using samples:

1. Go to BizTalk
   samples/orchestrations/consumeWebservice
   folder, install the
   ConsumeWebService application and
   publish POWebservice to IIS.
2. Change IIS Directory security
   permissions for POWebservice, remove
   anonymous or any other access.
3. Now drop the message you will see
   suspended messages because of HTTP
   status 401: Access Denied, then give
   access to POWebservice either
   anonymous or Windows.
4. Then resume
   the suspended instances, one will
   get disappear but
   another(orchestration) one wont.

Comment: Have you tried re-starting your host instance?

Comment: i did the hostinstance restart and after that i resumed the suspended orchestration instance still the same error.

Answer (score 5):

The orchestration will continue to fail with the exception because when it was suspended, the last persistence point was the receipt of the exception. This means that the orchestration will re-start (when resumed) and re-throw the exception.

Here's at article discussing some points at which orchestration state is persisted to the database: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanket/archive/2006/11/12/understanding-persistence-points-in-biztalk-orchestration.aspx

You can manipulate this to some extent in your orchestration design, as Richard Seroter discusses [here](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/orchestration-handling-of-suspended-messages/), but generally you would do better to use [failed message routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578516%28v=bts.70%29.aspx), enabling you to handle the failed messages, and terminate the failed orchestration instance.

Comment: Yes but we are not using failed message routing, is there any other way.

Comment: Another option is to manually save the message to a file, terminate the orchestration instance, and then resubmit the message. Here is an example of using Powershell to save suspended messages: http://winterdom.com/2006/09/btssuspendedmessaginginstanceswithpowershell

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but is this not just normal biztalk behavior? I am not 100% sure so please let me know if this is wrong:

The outbound messaging instance was suspended because the credentials the port was using to connect to to the DB were wrong.

This caused the orchestrations making these calls to also suspend.

The suspended message instance was resumed and was processed correctly because the problem was fixed. So the call was made to the DB.

However, the orchestration instance may not be able to resume because when resumed it found itself at the most recent persistence point and the original error which was delivered back from the send port is still available to the orchestration, causing it to re-suspend.

In the error message, it actually says "If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception."

If you want to handle this sort of thing you could make the call to the database atomic. That way the orchestration will not persist itself at the point of making the DB call. If the orchestration then suspends it will resume at a point before the DB call is made, and will make the DB call as normal, which should succeed this time because you have fixed the original issue.

The only problem with this is if your DB call cannot be executed more than once with the same data without bad things happenning (is not idempotent).

I am not 100% on the above explaination. Please point out if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Also Richard Seroter wronte a good article about this http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/orchestration-handling-of-suspended-messages/

Comment: Please explain the nature of your problem.

Comment: Creating the above scenario using Biztalk samples: 1.Go to BizTalk samples/orchestrations/consumeWebservice folder, install the ConsumeWebService application and publish POWebservice to IIS. 2.Change IIS Directory security permissions for POWebservice, remove anonymous or any other access. 3.Now drop the message you will see suspended messages because of HTTP status 401: Access Denied, then give access to POWebservice either anonymous or Windows. 4.Then resume the suspended instances, one will get disappear but another(orchestration) one wont.

Comment: i need a way to resume the orchestration instace successfully.

Answer (score 0):

this scenario not treated by Microsoft Biztalk = Middleware FAIL.

you have to solve this at the orchestration design stage up front...
http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/orchestration-handling-of-suspended-messages/